# Creating new environments in Puppet with Foreman does not work

Tags: puppet, foreman

I am new to Puppet and Foreman. I have installed Puppet with Foreman on a Ubuntu LTS 14.04 Server. I connect some Clients and change the Hostgroups. That works all fine.
But now I want to create a new environment in Foreman. Foreman shows me the new Environment, put after i put my clients in it, they show me a configuration failure. With `agent --test` they said, that there is no path in /etc/puppet/environments . And indeed, Foreman does not create here a folder or anything with the environment name. So its seems Foreman does not create the environment at all.

Has anyone a idea, how can i fix this? Why Foreman cant create new Environments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless things have changed in the past year, from my experience Foreman does not create environments.  It just tells that host to use an existing environment (rather than the default).  So the environment has to exist first before you can use it in Foreman.

Comment: Oh that explains a lot ! Thank you so much for this information.